# display only the title of the post into a certain category

Tags: posts, title

My site works with phrases and texts

In one category, the users send statements and debate about it.
In another category, are sent statements and debate about them.

I would like to show only the title of the post into a certain category, since they are not phrases and content needs, just the title.
in another category, the pots are usually shown, with title and content.

as might be the code in single.php

if you are in category X displays content and title
Y if the category content is not displayed, only the title

Comment: resolved, link : http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates

Comment: If you have answered your own question please consider adding that information in the form of an answer and marking it correct(it will aid in keeping your acceptance rate up to).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved, link : codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates